# Getting number of records against each row using SQL server

Tags: sql-server

I have table

```
col1 col2
---- ---- 
a    rrr
a    fff
b    ccc
b    zzz 
b    xxx
```

i want a query that return number of occurrences of col1 against each row like.

```
rows col1 col2
---- ---- ---- 
2    a    rrr
2    a    fff
3    b    ccc
3    b    zzz 
3    b    xxx
```

As a is repeated 2 time and b is repeated 3 time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `Count over partition_by_clause` which divides the result set produced by the FROM clause into partitions to which the function is applied.
This function treats all rows of the query result set as a single group

Try this...

```
select count (col1) over (partition by col1) [rows] ,col1 ,col2 from tablename
```

Comment: Request you to change `parttiton` to `partition`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`OVER` clause](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461(v=sql.110).aspx?ppud=4) with aggregate functions like `COUNT`:

```
SELECT rows = COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY col1),
       col1,
       col2
FROM dbo.TableName
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4e9eae/4/0)</kbd>